# Function converting char[] to array is not returning right value

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, char, int, type-conversion

I need to write a program that takes matrix from user in form [num1 num2; num 3 num4 etc] that is passed with pointer to a created table (another function counts rows and columns and creates appropriate array), then convert it into an array. I don't know why, the part which converts char to int makes crazy numbers. I.e. for input [1 3] it returns 1 as for first position and something over 20000 for second one.

```
void string_to_table(int **matrix,char text[])
{
    printf("start");
    int len=strlen(text);
    int out=0;
    int column=0;
    int row=0;
    int pos=1;
    int j=1;
    while(j<(len-1))
    {
        if(text[j]=='-')
            pos=-1;
        else if(text[j]>='0'&&text[j]<='9')
        {
            out=out+pos*(text[j]-48);
        }
        else if(text[j]==' ')
        {
            matrix[column][row]=out;
            out=0;
            pos=1;
            ++row;
        }
        else if(text[j]==';')
        {
            matrix[column][row]=out;
            out=0;
            pos=1;
            ++column;
            row=0;
        }
        else if(text[j]=='}')
            break;
        ++j;
    }
}
```

*edit for printing I use

```
void print_da_matrix(int **matrix, int i, int j)
{
    int k=0,l=0;
    printf("[");
    while(k<i)
    {
        while(l<j)
        {
            printf("%i",matrix[k][l]);
            printf(" ");
            ++l;
        }
        if(k<(i-1))
            printf(";");
        l=0;

            ++k;
    }
    printf("]");
}
```

where i and j are columns and rows counts.

Comment: Why do you think the second element is over 20000? Did you print out the contents of the array? If so, show the lines of code that did that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
out=out+pos*(text[j]-48);
```

should be

```
out = out*10 + pos*(text[j]-'0');
```

Also you need to do something about a space which does not follow a number, like the one after the ';'

Comment: Still, the second number goes nuts. It gives away some randow big number

Comment: Is there a space after the second number?  Your code ignores a ']'

Comment: No. When it reaches position len -1, which is ']' it ends

Comment: It ends, but doesn't save out if there is no space or ';'

Comment: Thank you very much. When I've replaced last if to if(text[j]==']')
            matrix[column][row]=out; and in while len-1 to len it started to work

Comment: If it solved your problem, please accept the answer.